# Test if object is es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, predicate

Using dynamics imports like that:

```
const i = import('./path/to/module.js');
```

yields a Promise for that module. Assuming that `./path/to/module.js` looks like that:

```
export function foo () {}
export function bar () {}
export default function () {}
```

the resulting object will have such a shape:

```
{
  foo: …
  bar: …
  default: …
}
```

Right now I need to figure out if a given Object is such a module, or any other one. So: **Is there any test to determine if a given object is such a es6 module, obtained by a dynamic import?**

Comment: If you are exporting a class from the module, you can check it using instanceOf.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Thanks for that hint. But I am not after checking the exported item, I'd like to ckeck if an object is an es6 module.

Answer (score 4):

You should check `Symbol.toStringTag` property of your alleged module object:

```
const isModule = i[Symbol.toStringTag] == 'Module'
```

See docs for [Symbol.toStringTag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag)